# Error when I try to check off POV-Ray 3.7 in Add-ons

Tags: add-on

When I try to add POV-Ray 3.7 to Blender 2.75a in Windows, I get the following message:

> Report Error
>   Trackback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75a\2.75\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line324, in enable mod=*import*(module_name)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75a\2.75\scripts\addons\render_povray_init_.py", line 56, in from.import(
>   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75a\2.75\scripts\addons\render_povray\render.py", line 32, in from.import df3 # for smoke rendering
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'df3'

I've downloaded [povwin-3.7-agpl3-setup.exe](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/POV-Ray), [povwin-3.7-editor.exe](http://www.povray.org/ftp/pub/povray/Official/povwin-3.7-agpl3-setup.exe) and [povwin-3.7-editor.exe](http://www.povray.org/download/povwin-3.7-editor.exe) into a folder on my desktop. I executed both installs but the message I got is still the same as stated above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Same here - when I try to enable the addon, it also results in an error message. If possible report this as bug. Expand the *Render: POV-Ray 3.7* panel and click *Report a bug*.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Blender program again when some library is missing (here df3)